# how to grep the error line and error caused by line

Tags: unix, grep

I need to grep the error.log file to get the `*ERROR*` and `Caused by:` for the same error tag in next-next lines

For example: i have the error.log like the following

```
08.02.2016 00:11:21.541 *ERROR* [158.151.84.34 [1454908281309] GET /content/user/home/people-search.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag Error while executing script content.jsp
org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException:
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib.IncludeTagHandler.dispatch(IncludeTagHandler.java:59)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib.AbstractDispatcherTagHandler.doEndTag(AbstractDispatcherTagHandler.java:129)
        at org.apache.jsp.libs.foundation.components.parsys.parsys_jsp._jspService(parsys_jsp.java:318)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
        ... 180 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: user person search is not available
08.02.2016 05:28:56.748 *ERROR* [158.151.84.34 [1454927336516] GET /content/user/home/people-search.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: user person search is not available
08.02.2016 06:11:24.725 *ERROR* [158.151.84.34 [1454908281309] GET /content/user/home/people-search.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag Error while executing script content.jsp
org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException:
        at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)
        ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: user person search is not available
```

I need to get the output as

```
08.02.2016 00:11:21.541 *ERROR* [158.151.84.34 [1454908281309] GET /content/user/home/people-search.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag Error while executing script content.jsp
Caused by: org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: user person search is not available
08.02.2016 05:28:56.748 *ERROR* [158.151.84.34 [1454927336516] GET /content/user/home/people-search.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: user person search is not available
08.02.2016 06:11:24.725 *ERROR* [158.151.84.34 [1454908281309] GET /content/user/home/people-search.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag Error while executing script content.jsp
Caused by: org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: user person search is not available
```

How will i get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
grep -e "\*ERROR\*" -e "Caused by:" error.log
```

Comment: this is good, i checked it and i got the expected the result as the error followed by its caused by, thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
egrep '\*ERROR\*|Caused by:' error.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you have a "Caused by:" line that wasn't preceded by an "ERROR" line? For example could you get a "WARNING" (or similar) followed by a "Caused by"? How about an "ERROR" that isn't followed by a "Caused by:"? How about either text in some other part of the line than where you are targeting (3rd field for ERROR, start of line for Caused by)? If any of that can happen then edit your question to include those cases in your sample input/output.

This is what you need to be safe from all of the above issues:

```
$ cat tst.awk        
/^[0-9]/ {
    if (inErr) {
        print "No cause found"
    }
    if ($3 == "*ERROR*") {
        print
        inErr = 1
    }
}
inErr && /^Caused by:/ {
    print
    inErr = 0
}
END {
    if (inErr) {
        print "No cause found"
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
08.02.2016 00:11:21.541 *ERROR* [158.151.84.34 [1454908281309] GET /content/user/home/people-search.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag Error while executing script content.jsp
Caused by: org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: user person search is not available
08.02.2016 05:28:56.748 *ERROR* [158.151.84.34 [1454927336516] GET /content/user/home/people-search.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: user person search is not available
08.02.2016 06:11:24.725 *ERROR* [158.151.84.34 [1454908281309] GET /content/user/home/people-search.html HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.wcm.tags.IncludeTag Error while executing script content.jsp
Caused by: org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: user person search is not available
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, below is simple and i get the expected result